# XQuery "except" expression is not producing a desired result

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I am using BaseX latest version 11.0 beta.

I am  trying to remove Texas cities in the `/root/base/r` sequence by using `/root/remove/r` sequence.

The goal is to use XQuery `except` expression.

**Here is my XML and XQuery**

```
declare context item := document {
<root>
  <base>
    <r>Miami</r>
    <r>Orlando</r>
    <r>Dallas</r>
    <r>Austin</r>
  </base>
  <remove>
    <r>Dallas</r>
    <r>Austin</r>
  </remove>
</root>
};

let $remove := /root/remove/r
return /root/base/r except $remove
```

**Desired output**

```
<r>Miami</r>
<r>Orlando</r>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the same initial XML

```
<r>Miami</r>
<r>Orlando</r>
<r>Dallas</r>
<r>Austin</r>
```

It is not clear what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25580552/395718). Or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50280595/395718)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `except`, the node references are compared, not their contents. For example, the following query will exclude nodes with the same node identity from the result:

```
let $remove := /root/base/r[position() > 2]
return /root/base/r except $remove
```

If you want to exclude all nodes of the `base` branch that have the string values of the nodes of the `$remove` branch, you can do this:

```
let $remove := /root/remove/r
return /root/base/r[not(. = $remove)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `except` operator compares nodes by node identity, not by string value.

You want

```
/root/base/r[not(. = /root/base/remove)]
```